# Turn Columns into multi level index pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

I have a DataFrame with lots of columns. I want the first column to be my first index the 5th column to be my 2nd level index and my 15th column to be my third level index. How may I do so? Please do forgive me for not supplying you with this DataFrame as it is long.

In other words, suppose I have the following code

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
   ...:           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
s1=s.reset_index(drop=0)
s1
```

How might I turn `s1` to `s`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to accomplish this.

```
>>> s1.set_index(['level_0', 'level_1'], drop=True)
                        0         1         2         3
level_0 level_1                                        
bar     one     -0.300791  0.013540  0.713098 -0.359717
        two      1.044732 -0.364056  1.055409  0.341651
baz     one      0.340860  0.092612 -0.275117  0.271777
        two      0.653210 -0.254870  0.745544 -1.787725
foo     one     -0.594016 -0.034900 -0.495453  0.153198
        two      0.852272 -2.460928 -0.248302  0.534830
qux     one     -0.396236  0.302698  1.791999  0.422901
        two      1.379244 -0.612005 -0.614633 -0.538105
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and `miradulo`'s answer didn't quite work for me in jupyter notebook.

I found that `.sort_index()` helped me get exactly what I wanted:

```
s1.set_index(['level_0', 'level_1']).sort_index()

level_0 level_1                                        
bar     one     -0.300791  0.013540  0.713098 -0.359717
        two      1.044732 -0.364056  1.055409  0.341651
baz     one      0.340860  0.092612 -0.275117  0.271777
        two      0.653210 -0.254870  0.745544 -1.787725
foo     one     -0.594016 -0.034900 -0.495453  0.153198
        two      0.852272 -2.460928 -0.248302  0.534830
qux     one     -0.396236  0.302698  1.791999  0.422901
        two      1.379244 -0.612005 -0.614633 -0.538105
```

Comment: PS: if someone could help me with the markdown, it would be welcome! ;)

Comment: please check here to fix your markdown https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code